# Show the \subtitle if not empty

Tags: titles, conditionals

How do I show the subtitle if it's defined?

When have a subtitle the code is like this:

```
\begin{center}
 \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\thetitle:}}\\
 \MakeTextUppercase{\thesubtitle}
\{center}
```

[image]

And when don't have a subtitle, it would be like this:

```
\begin{center}
 \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\thetitle}}
\{center}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

This is the `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

%% This is how the Class abntex2 create the command '\titulo' for the title
%\newcommand{\titulo}[1]{\title{#1}}
%\newcommand{\imprimirtitulo}{\thetitle}
% ---
%% This is how I created the command '\subtitulo' for the subtitle
\providecommand{\imprimirsubtitulo}{} % means 'print subtitle'
\newcommand{\subtitulo}[1]{\renewcommand{\imprimirsubtitulo}{#1}}
% ---
% Changing the cover page
\renewcommand{\imprimircapa}{% means 'print cover page'
    \begin{capa}%
        \center

        \vspace*{3,5cm}

        \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\imprimirinstituicao}}

        \vspace*{2cm}

        \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\imprimirautor}}

        \vspace*{3cm}
        \begin{center}
        \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\imprimirtitulo:}}\\
        \MakeTextUppercase{\imprimirsubtitulo{}}
        \end{center}
        \vfill

        \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\imprimirlocal}}

        \textbf{\imprimirdata}
    \end{capa}
}
% ---

\titulo{The title}
\subtitulo{subtitle}
\autor{Author}
\local{Local}
\data{2015}
\instituicao{Institution}

\begin{document}

\imprimircapa

\end{document}
```

Note: I'm Brazilian, and the class that I'm using is in Portuguese.

Comment: Welcome! Since this is not a standard command, we cannot help without more information. If you make your code into a complete, small document we can compile, we'll understand your situation.

Comment: `\thetitle` and `\thesubtitle` look like they are defined as counter format macros, this is 'weird'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have defined the sub-title macro and title-placement yourself, there are plenty of options. For example, you can also define an `\if`-condition, say, `\ifsubtitle`, and condition accordingly. That is

```
\ifsubtitle
  <true clause>
\else
  <false clause>
\fi
```

In your case one could leave the `\else` (`<false clause>`) out/empty.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

%% This is how the Class abntex2 create the command '\titulo' for the title
%\newcommand{\titulo}[1]{\title{#1}}
%\newcommand{\imprimirtitulo}{\thetitle}
% ---
%% This is how I created the command '\subtitulo' for the subtitle
\providecommand{\imprimirsubtitulo}{} % means 'print subtitle'
\newif\ifsubtitle% Default is \subtitlefalse
\newcommand{\subtitulo}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\imprimirsubtitulo}{#1}%
  \global\subtitletrue}
% ---
% Changing the cover page
\renewcommand{\imprimircapa}{% means 'print cover page'
  \begin{capa}%
    \centering

    \vspace*{3.5cm}

    \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\imprimirinstituicao}}

    \vspace*{2cm}

    \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\imprimirautor}}

    \vspace*{3cm}

    \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\imprimirtitulo}}%
    \ifsubtitle
      \textbf{:}\\
      \MakeTextUppercase{\imprimirsubtitulo{}}
    \fi

    \vfill

    \MakeTextUppercase{\textbf{\imprimirlocal}}

    \textbf{\imprimirdata}
  \end{capa}
}
% ---

\titulo{The title}
\subtitulo{subtitle}
\autor{Author}
\local{Local}
\data{2015}
\instituicao{Institution}

\begin{document}

\imprimircapa

\end{document}
```

I've made some subtle changes to the `\imprimircapa` macro as well.